# Flip flop operator in perl

Tags: perl, loops

I have a requirement where I need to execute a statement inside the loop for the first occurrence of a variable.

For example:
Given array my `@rand_numbers = qw(1 2 1 2 3 1 3 2);` 
I know that there are only 3 values present in the array (i.e in this case 1,2 and 3)
I want to print something (or do something) on the first encounter of each value(only in the first encounter and never repeat it for the consecutive encounter of the corresponding value).

Following is one approach

```
my @rand_numbers = qw(1 2 1 2 3 1 3 2); 
my $came_across_1=0, $came_across_2=0, $came_across_3=0;

for my $x(@rand_numbers) { 
    print "First 1\n" and $came_across_1=1 if($x==1 and $came_across_1==0); 
    print "First 2\n" and $came_across_2=1 if($x==2 and $came_across_2==0); 
    print "First 3\n" and $came_across_3=1 if($x==3 and $came_across_3==0); 
    print "Common op for -- $x \n"; 
}
```

Is there a way to achieve above result with no variable like `$came_across_x` ? [i.e. with the help of flip-flop operator?]

Thanks,
Ranjith

Answer (score 11):

This may not work for your real-life situation, but it works for your sample, and may give you an idea:

```
my %seen;
for my $x (@rand_numbers) {
  print "First $x\n" unless $seen{$x}++;
  print "Common op for -- $x\n"
}
```

Comment: Assuming what you want to do is the same for each different item you encounter, you can easily factor it into a subroutine and write `do_for_first($x) unless $seen{$x}++; do_for_all($x);`

Comment: Hi Chris, my main motive was not to use a temporary variable [like in this case you have used '%seen' hash]. Sorry if my question was confusing. However for this scenario what you have suggested is the optimal approach, but to understand the available one-liners in perl i was wondering if we could do it only using flip-flop operator(or some other special variable/special operator).

Comment: @Ranjith Note that using a single hash table is about a bazijillion times better and more flexible than your `$came_across_i` variables.

Comment: @Ranjith - If you don't want to see the temporary variable you could do `{ my %seen_data; sub seen { @_ ? $seen_data{$_[0]}++ : %seen_data = () } }`. Before your loop call `seen;` to clear the hash (just in case you use it elsewhere) then in the loop replace `unless $seen{$x}++` with `seen $x`. Then after the loop call `seen;` again to clear it. Actually you could (should?) put this all in a module and make the different operations a bit clearer but the basic principle still stands.

Comment: As for your concerns about wanting to use the flip-flop operator and not wanting to use temporary variables: hammers are for nails and screwdrivers are for screws. The best way to know if you've seen something is to store it somewhere when you see it. This is the most readable way to do this, and you'll see this code (or something similar: `@list = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @list` creates a list of unique values) used a lot in Perl. You probably can do it with the flip-flop operator, but people complain about Perl being unreadable enough as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a hash as @Chris suggests.

Using the flip-flop operator seems to be not practical here because you'll need to keep track of seen variables anyway:

```
my %seen;
for (@rand_numbers) {
    print "$_\n" if $_ == 1 && !$seen{$_}++ .. $_ == 1;
    print "$_\n" if $_ == 2 && !$seen{$_}++ .. $_ == 2;
    print "$_\n" if $_ == 3 && !$seen{$_}++ .. $_ == 3;
}
```